# Anti-Photography Technology?

Tags: science-based, near-future, hardcopy

Are there any current or emerging technologies that would make it difficult to copy documents? I've looked for things, but I've mostly found technology for preventing making authentic-looking duplicates of an original, but I'm trying to create something more like a top secret document than a sports ticket.

**EDIT**

The specific scenario has an associate of our intrepid heroes in a bureaucrats office, unattended for a few minutes. I need a reason why they'd be able to quickly skim a document, but not just whip out the camera app.

Comment: Copiers with defunct machinery and/or software problems?

Comment: If it's readable by human eyes then it still could be copied.

Comment: [That kind of stuff ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMR25RSOzFo) The easiest way of doing it is imposing some rules to the producers of copying devices. But most likely, a spy will not respect them.

Comment: Reminder to all answerers: Please adhere to the requirements of the [tag:hard-science] tag. Also, can you explain how this relates to a world a bit? Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of copy?  As you saw, most technologies attempt to prevent authentic-looking duplication, because the particular piece of paper has legal power.  Are you simply looking to make it hard to copy the information out of a document, such as the dark maroon pens they use to declassify documents?

Comment: @CortAmmon Yeah, something preventing someone who has a cell phone camera and 90 seconds from copying down a 4-5 page document.

Comment: @tikiking1 Are you really sure you want [hard-science] here? It's easy to reason your way to an answer, based on current sciences including optics and photography, and explain how those sciences lead to the proposed answer, but I'm not sure there are any easy-to-find *scientific references* as required by the presence of the hard-science tag, to back up such an answer. May I suggest editing to replace the hard-science tag with science-based instead? (Hint: it seems to me that the only answer so far that meets the hard-science criteria at all is Radovan Garabík's.)

Comment: Actually kind of such thing does exist. Google "anti photography glasses" and "paparazzi proof clothing".

Comment: I'm not a scientist, so I'm not even going to attempt to answer this question, but I suspect the answer might include: "Magnets, magnets everywhere," that might disrupt electrical equipment meant to copy a document.

Comment: An MRI might help. Or if you could make it a requirement to read the document while dunking your head under water. Obviously, that wouldn't work if your heroes brought along with them a water proof cell phone or a water proof camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Print holographic documents, like advanced versions of the holograms you see on credit cards.

Depending on the angle at which you hold it, you see different content. If it is made for two human eyes, a single lens camera won't be able to capture a meaningful image, not in a single photograph, and if the text is small enough, a video recording may not have the necessary resolution.

Comment: All the answers here are good, but this one fits my story best. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that in order for a human to see the document there needs to be light in the correct color coming off the document.

If an eye can see it then a camera can record it.

There are tricks that can be done that will defeat certain cameras or copiers such as requiring, emitting, or absorbing certain light. Someone will always be able to come up with a camera that fixes it though.

The best idea I can come up with right now is to use two documents and a separator with a mirror on each side. Place the two documents lined up and they get combined by your eyes to reveal the message. Even then though a specially designed camera (or just software processing after you copy each individual document) would reveal the hidden message.

You need to control access to the documents, once someone has them then you've lost.

Answer (score 4):

## The obfuscation industry presents:

[image: EMP]

**Featuring a continuously generated electromagnetic pulse ([EMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse#Non-nuclear_electromagnetic_pulse_.28NNEMP.29)) safely destroying any nearby photographic equipment.** (Or any other electric or electronic equipment for that matter.)

Batteries are not included.

Comment: Y'know, I've been wondering this for a while, but is it possible to make an EMP-emitting device that doesn't burn itself out when it pulses?

Comment: @user867 I don't see why it wouldn't be, though incorporating it (and the batteries) into something paper-sized might be quite a challenge. In a sense, an EMP is just a very, very strong radio transmission usually of very short duration. We know how to make hugely powerful radio transmitters, but they tend to come with other requirements...

Comment: And this won't affect traditional silver-based photography...

Comment: Still can be captured with a panel camera operating in a proper Faraday-cage.

Answer (score 3):

Making the paper highly radioactive will do it - the radiation will saturate those optical sensors (this is what lead Becquerel to the discovery of radioactivity). As a bonus, it will be very unhealthy for the thieves/spies to handle the documents. Of course, this is rather impractical for a real application.

As a side note, [Marie Curie's research papers are still radioactive](http://www.openculture.com/2015/07/marie-curies-research-papers-are-still-radioactive-100-years-later.html).

Comment: Would this still apply to, e.g. a cell phone camera?

Comment: Given how absurdly radioactive the documents would have to be for this to work I have some doubts about how plausible this is.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a little harder to make a copy of your document but that would include to work with any manufacturer of digital cameras and scanners/copiers.

You could print a code (like the one that is already printed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_steganography) which doesn't allow to make a copy / photo.

But that still could be hacked or you could just take a photo with an analog camera.

Or, as mentioned above, you could make a EMP-Emmiting Document but that'd probably be too expensive and you could still take a photo with an analog camera.

The safest way for a document would be to only have a crypted digital copy, other wise it could ever be copied or stolen.

Comment: An encrypted digital copy is useless. It needs to be decrypted to be viewed, at which point someone can point their cell phone camera at the computer screen, or copy the contents manually to a separate device (such as a cell phone or laptop).

Comment: True, but it's very unlikely that a "top secret" document will be decrypted on the screen while the "bureaucrat" is outside the office.

Answer (score 1):

You face quite a challenge.  Physics and information theory are against you, and they are not kind foes.  Fundamentally, eyes detect photons reflected or emitted off of the surface of the page.  If there are photons for the eye to detect, there are photons for a camera to detect.

This is why real security always focuses on verifying that people can be trusted first, and only locks down the technology when they can no longer trust the people enough.  Historically speaking, the trustworthiness of people is always the limiting factor of security,  and your heros demonstrate that they probably cannot be trusted with a document.  Technology can always be bypassed (obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/538/) Reference):

[image: Obligatory XKCD reference]

Accordingly, expect whatever solution you come up with to be extremely fanciful.  Nobody with reasonably normal documents would ever secure them in a way which prevents cell phones from taking pictures of them (short of simply preventing anyone from having cell phones in the area in the first place).  However, in the unreasonable category, we could contort the concept of EYES ONLY, a security classification caveat which indicates that the information in the document should not be disseminated to anyone who has not been physically shown the document, no matter what their clearance is.  What if we took that literally, and caveated something as TOP SECRET//EYEBALLS ONLY?
[image: Eyeball]

What if the document was housed in a special container designed for TOP SECRET//EYEBALLS ONLY documents.  It might have a pair of holes at eye level to permit viewing of the documents inside.  Of course, we're going to need to stop the heroes from simply putting the camera up to the hole.  What if each hole contained a retina scanner or an iris scanner?  If they detected anything except a living human eyeball peering through them, they'd shutter and alert security.  As an added bonus, now the data is protected by a biometric scanner as well! (good luck heroes!)

This would lead naturally to an amrs race in spy technology.  Spies would invent specialized contacts with small cameras in them, but the box could attempt to detect those as well.  Permit that cat and mouse game to continue at your leisure until it reaches the level of Mission Impossible you want to see for your story.

Who would go to such lengths?  I have no idea, but it might work.  Perhaps the aliens they keep in Area-51 are actually the cover-up for something even more secretive.  The truth is out there, it's just EYEBALLS ONLY.

Answer (score 1):

bureaucrats like procedures and other red tape like things.  The easiest way is to restrict tech access. Cell phones and other electronics have to be 'checked-in' and not allowed in the building.  Many courthouses do this already.

Next, places with documents can put restrictions on the copier machines, needing a 'login' to be able to make any copies. Same could be said for printers.

So its a low-tech approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This one depends heavily on the world you're in and the type of organization your character is from but with that caveat in mind.

**DRM**

[image]

http://www.zdnet.com/article/apple-files-patent-to-prevent-concert-piracy-with-infrared-tech/

So assuming we're in a near-future world. Your character only has a bog-standard, unsuspicious, commodity hardware camera phone in his pocket.

He whips it out to try to snap a photo but it flashes up a copyright warning and switches off the camera. He didn't expect this.

The office in question is quite concerned about illegitimate copying so they have a set of the same sort of IR emitters used in cinemas dotted around the office constantly transmitting the "do not record" signal meant and any consumer cameras listen to that signal.

No movies or photos can be recorded in that room unless you have a black market or old camera which doesn't comply with the countries copyright laws.Not a big deal if you know about it in advance but the character didn't know about it.  So he puts away his phone and skims the document by eye.

Comment: The future looks scary. D:

Answer (score 0):

Laminate the documents with transparent reflective films. It will make photo copiers give nothing but white.

This will not prevent using a
camera though...

EDIT: No, you cannot. Or rather: you should not.

**If** it is important for you that documents may not be copied, then you need to take things more seriously then relying on this anti-photography technology. Then you need to be in tight control of who gets to see them, where and under what conditions. And the premise of the question states that this is not happening.

While you may - eventually - find a somewhat credible technology for your question, the **premise** of the question is flawed in that you are left with an organisation that supposedly cares about the security of their documents, but that at the same time are incredibly lax in the handling of them and instead fall back on this technology, thus creating an RMS Titanic-like scenario.

Comment: For a (LCD) camera, make the document radiate in near infrared (witness the trick of pointing your TV remote towards a cellphone camera). This might be difficult without a power source, though. And can be circumvented with a proper filter, once it becomes known.

Comment: What if the documents were held in a really low light location (the documents must remain in the office), forcing the camera user to use the flash, which would result in the same white as the photocopier.

Comment: Well you always have the problem that if you can see it, then you can photograph it. An eye and a camera are too similar. The easiest way is most likely to prevent devices near the documents.

Comment: The phrase in the OP, "whip out the camera app" doesn't make it sound like the spies have hi-tech photography equipment. Taking photographs with mobile phone cameras can be difficult in low light conditions even when it's clear to the human eye

Comment: Actually my current phone - an S6 - has quite excellent low light capabilities. I was surprised. So I would say that even against amateur spies that rely on phone cameras,  you're outta luck if you are trying to make documents that can be seen but not photographed.

Answer (score 0):

What if the documents are not actually on sheets of paper but on microfilm or some equivalent, and the only device to hand to use them is a microscope-like viewer which the camera can't see into.

Comment: A device of that type would need an eye-piece large enough for a human eye (obviously) so any camera smaller than that would be able to see into it. (Similar to putting a cell phone up to the viewfinder of an analog camera)

Answer (score 0):

how about this: the building has, located somewhere within it, a powerful radio antenna broadcasting at a certain frequency. this frequency probably doesnt cause the effects of an EMP, but im not sure if that would be scientifically possible. anyway, sensitive documents are fitted with a series of wires and paper-thin circuitry that is able to pick up the signal and convert it into short-range EMP pulses. while not being read, the papers are kept in a safe with a faraday cage around it, and the whole building is preferably also surrounded by one to prevent to signal getting out. this would get around the problem of internal power sources, and still allow people at the building to work with electronics.